# Why is a model one-time readable in an AngularJS controller?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to read a model from inside a controller. Say I have this controller

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = {title: 'foo'};

    $scope.log = function() {
      console.log($scope.data);
    }
  });
```

And this markup

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input ng-model="data.title">
  <button ng-click="log()">log</button>  
</div>
```

When I press the button the *first* time it works, also if I modified the value, but all subsequent clicks just logs the first model again, no matter if the input data is changed.

What am I not getting? Should I use something else for this purpose? A service?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/J6jLz/1/

**Update**
Curiously it works if I log the 'title' property prior to logging the actual data object: http://jsfiddle.net/Yf5kz/4/

Does this have to do with `$apply` on the scope maybe?

Comment: Strange, as your fiddle seems to be working OK for me (Chrome). I mean, clicking on the button logs the value from the input box - no matter if this is the first or subsequent click.

Comment: So if you click (logs 'foo' value), change input to 'bar' and click, does it log the 'bar' value?

Comment: Yes. It logs `Object {title: "foo"}` and `Object {title: "bar"}` to be precise.

Comment: Okay so this is a Chrome issue. It works in Firefox. What version Chrome are you using?

Comment: even simpler way to view it is put this in page: `<pre>{{data | json}}` will see it update as you type  http://jsfiddle.net/J6jLz/2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead

```
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.data));
```

Comment: That's sort of the same solution as mentioned in the update. It works, but it doesn't really explain or solve the issue. I'd like to not have to reference (or "use"?) the `data` property before reading from it. It smells.

Comment: As for "explain": I think Chrome doesn't see a change to the $scope.data object reference, so it doesn't show you anything new.  With stringify, obviously Chrome doesn't have previous object reference to compare it to, so it always prints something.

Comment: That makes sense. But would you not say that this is an issue that should be handled by Angular? I mean, Angular should make sure the object (reference) is changed/updated so Chrome can read the new data.

Comment: I would not say this is an Angular issue.  If a property of the object changes, the object reference (i.e., what $scope.data points to) has not changed.